# Intersection of two spans

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathrm{span}\{ {v_1}...{v_j}\}  \cap \mathrm{span}\{ {v_{j + 1}}...{v_n}\}  \ne \{ 0\} $.

So, there's a vector, not $0_v$ in the intersection.

Why does it imply that there exist $a_i, b_i$, not all zero, such that

${a_1}{v_1}...{a_j}{v_j} = {b_{j + 1}}{v_{j + 1}}...{b_n}{v_n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span of a set of vectors is defined as the set of all linear combinations of those vectors. Since the intersection of the spans is nonzero, it follows that there exists a vector which can be written as linear combination of the vectors of the first set and as a linear combination of the vectors of the second set, so the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\span}{span}$The span of any set of vectors contains the zero vector. So if $\text{span}\{ {v_1}...{v_j}\}  \cap \text{span}\{ {v_{j + 1}}...{v_n}\}  \ne \{ 0\} $, then there must be a *non-zero* vector in the intersection.

That is, some non-zero linear combination of the vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^j$ must equal some non-zero linear combination of the $\{v_i\}_{i=j+1}^n$:
$$
a_1v_1 + \dots + a_jv_j = b_{j+1}v_{j+1} + \dots + b_nv_n.
$$